# Errors that won't solve, can't figure how to fix them and it's not a bad format problem this time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's me, again. I worked a lot on my game since last question, but only have added like 3 lines to my player script and it says that it expects a bracket in `Start()` fonction after `Health = MaxHealth;` which isn't normal. I feel like it's easily fixable but eh... looks like my hours trying to fix my problem didn't change anything, so I hope y'all pros can use a bit of magic. Thank you.[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCore : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Health Variables
    public int MaxHealth = 2;

    public int Health;

    // Other Variables
    private bool DelayCheck = true;
    [SerializeField] private Jump jump;
    [SerializeField] private Bar_Manager bar_manager;    
    // Part about taking damage and taking damage when colliding with platforms that do damage and level borders
    public void TakeDamage(int Damage)
    {
        Health = Health - Damage;
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Death.SetActive(true);
    }

    IEnumerator DelayBetweenDamage()
    {
        DelayCheck = false;
        TakeDamage(1);
        Debug.Log("Player took 1 damage.");
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        DelayCheck = true;
    }

    // Take Damage when touching platforms with the DMG_platform tag
    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "DMG_platform" && DelayCheck == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DelayBetweenDamage());
        }
    }

    // Take fatal damages when falling or going out of the map borders
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Level_Border")
        {
            TakeDamage(MaxHealth);
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Part about Bonus getting triggered and applying them to the player

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Power")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);

            // if player touches Power Jump Bonus
            if (col.gameObject.name == "PowerJump")
            {
                jump.jumpVelocity = 19f;
            }
            
            // if player touches Power Health Bonus
            if (col.gameObject.name == "PowerHealth")
            {
                MaxHealth = 3;
                bar_manager.slider.maxValue = MaxHealth;
                if (Health <= 2)
                {
                    Health = Health + 1;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Health = MaxHealth;
        public GameObject Death = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Death_Screen");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Dies if Health is less than 0 
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (I tried reformating it)

Comment: You can't use `public` modifier inside a method (next line), that's why it's complaining.  `public GameObject Death` should be outside of a method.

Comment: If you use `GameObject Death` inside the function you're declaring a local variable that will cease to exist once the function ends. It seems like you want that to be a field in the class, like the others under `// Other Variables` at the top.

Comment: Please, post the actual error text instead of just a picture of it.  See: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks, I'll send actual error texts as of now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `}` after `Health = MaxHealth;` and before your `public GameObject Death` Property:

```
void Start()
{
   Health = MaxHealth;
}

public GameObject Death = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Death_Screen");
```

Or as @Wyck suggests:

```
public GameObject Death;

void Start()
{
   Health = MaxHealth;
   Death = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Death_Screen");
}
```

Comment: I think there's more to it than that.  The variable should be declared outside the function as `public GameObject Death;` And I'd be tempted to assign it in the editor, but if not, then the assignment of a value to `Death` should probably happen in the `Start` method still. `Death = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Death_Screen");`

Comment: If that is the case, what you suggest is valid.

Comment: I fixed it by declaring the variable 'public GameObject Death' outside of the fonction and made it so it assings in ' Start() ' fonction, thanks for lighting me up on it, from now on, I'll keep myself away from declaring variables in fonctions haha thanks a lot :)

Comment: @LeFauconQC There is nothing wrong with declaring local variables in a function. In the contrary, every variable should be defined in the narrowest scope possible. You just can't make them `public`. And if you need something to be available in the whole class you must define it outside of the function.

Comment: oh alright I got you